# Redirecting from a search form with express?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm new to this and trying to call an external API after typing a term in a search form and redirecting to a new page with the results. This is what I have so far.

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const url =
  'https://www.example.com/api/search_term?query=';

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});

app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
  res.render('search', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' });
});

app.post('/results', (req, res) => {
  const term = req.body.term;
  request(`${url}term`, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log(body);
    }
  });
});
```

My PUG file is simply a search form for now. Since I'm making a call to an external api I got confused as to redirecting from a `get` request.

I want to load the app, set the search form as the home page, submit a term to search and then redirect to another page containing the results.

Am I wrong to think that I need to redirect to another `get` route that "grabs" the results from the initial `get` route which contains the search form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I wrong to think that I need to redirect to another get route that "grabs" the results from the initial get route which contains the search form

Yes, you are.

You need two routes and no redirections at all.

1. The route which serves the HTML form
2. The route which reads the submitted form data and returns the HTML formatted search results

The browser should request the second route because its URL is specified in the `action` attribute of the form.

`console.log(body);` should be replaced with a call to `res.render` that includes the search results to be rendered in the template.